# Safetensors are slower than torch.load. Why?

Tags: pytorch, huggingface

Lately, I have been testing safetensors. It claims that the safetensors are faster and safer than pickle. So I did my own comparison with the code below:

```
    start_time = time.time()
    with open("./pytorch_model.bin", "rb") as f:
        tensors = torch.load(f, map_location="cpu")
    print(time.time() - start_time)
    start_time = time.time()
    model.load_state_dict(tensors)
    print(time.time() - start_time)

    start_time = time.time()
    tensors = load_file("./model.safetensors", device="cpu")
    print(time.time() - start_time)
    start_time = time.time()
    model.load_state_dict(tensors)
    print(time.time() - start_time)
```

The **torch load** takes 0.9035871028900146 seconds.

**Loading state dict with tensors loaded using torch load** takes 0.14872288703918457 seconds.

**Safetensors** load takes 0.14471077919006348 seconds.

**Loading state dict with tensors loaded using safetensors load** takes 5.597403526306152 seconds.

When it comes to loading tensors safetensors load function clearly wins and is faster but why the same tensors take 5 seconds to instantiate the model?
Torch loaded and safentesors loaded tensors are the same. Why does it then take way more time?